# Is there a way to display the (x,y) value of a specific value in a chart?

Tags: excel, vba, charts, visualization

```
Sub ProductionDistribution()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim xData As Range
Dim yData As Range
Dim xData2 As Range
Dim yData2 As Range
Dim xData3 As Range
Dim yData3 As Range
Dim xData4 As Range
Dim yData4 As Range


Set xData = Range("Dates")
Set yData = Range("CumFeed")

Set xData2 = Range("Dates")
Set yData2 = Range("CumTails")

Set xData3 = Range("Dates")
Set yData3 = Range("CumSinter")

Set xData4 = Range("Dates")
Set yData4 = Range("CumSuper")

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = Sheets("Report")

Dim chtObj As ChartObject
Set chtObj = ws.ChartObjects.Add(Width:=249, Height:=150.7, Left:=Range("G6").Left, Top:=Range("G6").Top)

Dim cht As Chart
Set cht = chtObj.Chart
cht.HasLegend = True
cht.Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionCorner
cht.ChartStyle = 7
```

So I'm working with this macro and would like to display the last value of a series on the chart, is there a function to choose a specific point to display or a chart style that allows you to select?

You can see that I have Style #234 enabled but it causes the value at every point to be displayed.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text and not as an image.

Comment: I'm sure John Walkenbach wrote some code that pulls data from a chart.... haven't found it yet though.